Updating rows in MUI DataGrid (community version) without upserting?
MUI DataGrid has an updateRows() method that I use to update some rows after I fetch more data from backend. The problem is that the table data is connected to a search field which can lead to the following bug happening;

The user stops typing just long enough for the search query to go out
The user starts typing again while data is being fetched for the rows from the previous search results
The results from step 2 are shown as expected but the results from step 1 are inserted as the data queries resolve...

My question therefore is whether there's any way to use the updateRows() function without inserting/upserting the row if the id is no longer found in the table?
The only "modifier" to updateRows() that I can find in docs is _action: "delete", but there's no mention of any way to stop the function from upserting. So for now I'm just disabling the search field while the row queries resolve. This works but is not the best UX... Any better suggestions?
